# Is it possible to extend a class method in JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a class `A` with the following method:

```
  foo(x, options) {
    const limit = options && options.limit ? options.limit : undefined;
    const select = options && options.select ? options.select : {};
    const paginate = options && options.paginate ? options.paginate : {};
    const sort = options && options.sort ? options.sort : {};
    const count = options && options.count;

    const args = deepMerge({ x }, paginate);

    return count ? this.model.find(args).count()
      : this.model.find(args).limit(limit).select(select).sort(sort);
  }
```

Then I create a class `B` that extends `A`. There I have a method `bar` that is almost identical to method `foo`.

Is it possible to extend method `bar` to have limit,select,paginate,sort and count? I don't want to override `foo` method in `B` class, so I need it to have a distinct name

Comment: You can implement `bar(x, options) { ... }` on `B` and call [`super.foo(x, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) from within the definition to get what the base class would return.

Comment: But what if I don't want to override `foo`? Say, I want to use `foo` and `bar` in `B` instance as they will serve different goals

Comment: Show a complete SSCCE with 'bar'.

Comment: Can you please post what your solution would look like if you *did* overwrite `foo`?

Comment: This is an unclear question. You can just create a `bar()` method in the derived class B and have it take whatever arguments you want.  So far, that has nothing to do with `foo()` in the parent class at all.  Then, if you want to call `foo()` from within `bar()` and pass it the arguments it wants, you can do that with `this.foo(...)` from within `bar()`. None of this overrides `foo()` in any way. 
 `foo()` and `bar()` are different methods.  `bar()` just happens to call `this.foo()` as part of its implementation, just like it can call any other method in B or A. NOT clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `this.foo()` if you haven't overwritten the `foo()` method on `B`, else, you can use the `super` keyword which refers to the parent class instance `super.foo()` and it works in both cases (overwritten or not).

```
class B extends A {
    bar(){
      super.foo();
    }
}
```

> **Disclaimer:** I'm assuming that: by class, you mean ES6 classes not ES5 prior prototypes.

Working example:

```js
class A {
  foo() {
    return 'value of A';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // case you override the method
  // super.foo() still points to the 
  // original A.foo() but you don't
  // have to do this, it's just an
  // example
  foo() {
    return 'value of B';
  }
  
  bar() {
    const valueOfA = super.foo();
    
    return valueOfA;
  }
}

const b = new B();

console.log(b.bar())
```